# Should my question really be on hold?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, homework-and-exercises, specific-question

I posted this question:
[Where do these formulas for an object being pushed up an incline come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101663/object-at-incline-and-forces-acting-on-it)

I think I showed enough effort, I am not asking someone to do my homework, I am not asking someone to check my answers, and I am not being unclear on what I am having problems with.

The main idea of my question is I have a book which has two formulas; I am trying to prove them to see how the author arrived at them and I need help.

Let me know if my question should be closed. If so I'll gladly delete it myself.

Comment: Note that the policy is about homework - _like_ problems, proofs and all usually fall under it.

Comment: •"Homework-like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem." I am asking about a specific physics concept, gravity/force in relation to an object on a slope. Plus I showed all of my work, which is right but maybe a bit magical on how I got there and perhaps not the correct way to arrive at the equations.

Comment: I don't see any specific concept. You have a final result and are wondering how to get there, there's nothing specific about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is certainly better than a lot of the low-quality homework questions we get here, but at its core, what you're asking is "where do these formulas come from?" That's not a conceptual question. What we mean by asking about a specific physics concept is something like "What does the sin(theta) in this equation represent?" or "Is it valid to set w cos(theta) = 0 here?" (where you would present reasons why you think it might not be but you're not sure) or even "Why is this block able to slide up the incline when my calculations show that it shouldn't be able to?" Basically, you're supposed to dig down into your work and identify the one specific idea that you can't understand or figure out, which is keeping you from proceeding with the problem. A good rule of thumb is that you should be able to ask your one question in the title, and it shouldn't be "how do I derive this?"

So the bottom line is, no, you haven't showed enough effort. You're fairly close, though. With a little discussion here on meta we could probably help you figure out how to edit your question so that it would be on topic.

Comment: ok thank you for telling me more what a homework question is